# Tags to Post-ID mysql query. Tag Search

Tags: posts, mysql, search, tags

Im trying to implement a tag-based search. When i specify certain tags, tagged posts will be searched and the post-id will be displayed that matches the searchcriteria.

Currently it only works for a single tag.

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT $wpdb->posts.ID FROM $wpdb->terms
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON ($wpdb->terms.term_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id)
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON ($wpdb->terms.term_id = $wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id)
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->posts ON ($wpdb->term_relationships.object_id = $wpdb->posts.ID)
        WHERE $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'post_tag' " . $substring;
```

Substring looks like following:

```
$substring = "AND $wpdb->terms.slug IN ('tag1','tag2')"
```

And here is the problem. It does not look for single posts that match all criteria. Instead it 'collects' all posts with all tags searched.

For example:

```
// postid1 -> tag1
// postid2 -> tag2
// postid3 -> tag1, tag2

$substring = "AND $wpdb->terms.slug IN ('tag1')"
//Output: postid1, postid3 - - - CORRECT
$substring = "AND $wpdb->terms.slug IN ('tag1','tag2')"
//Output: postid1, postid2, postid3 - - -WRONG!

//Expected: postid3
```

So far i have no idea howto solve it in a single mysql query. Maybe im missing something.
Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are normal `IN` mechanics - it matches anything in set, not all of set combined.

Type of match you want is called [`tag_slug__and`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Tag_Parameters) in WP query arguments. You can see code that generates SQL for it in source of [`WP_Query->&get_posts()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.4/wp-includes/query.php#L1995) method.

Resulting SQL is like this:

```
SELECT p.ID 
FROM wp_posts p 
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships tr ON (p.ID = tr.object_id) 
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON (tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id) 
INNER JOIN wp_terms t ON (tt.term_id = t.term_id) 
WHERE tt.taxonomy = 'post_tag' 
AND t.slug IN ('is', 'filler') 
GROUP BY p.ID HAVING count(p.ID) = 2
```

Comment: ok i understand. So when i search more then 2 tags i have to change the count plus list am i right?

Comment: @proxylittle yes, seems so.